# How to instruct Capistrano to use ZSH instead of BASH?

Tags: ubuntu, capistrano, zsh

On a deployment server we have ZSH set as the default shell for the deployment user.  On login this works fine, however when `cap deploy` is run, it appears to be executing bash instead of zsh as it has problems with a few specific zsh commands which are not recognized.  It's not a serious problem, but I'd like to eliminate this by instructing the deployment script to use zsh instead of bash.  How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the following line to you deploy.rb

```
default_run_options[:shell] = '/bin/zsh'
```